# Alternative way to say "closest to the direction pointed at"?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-request

> A blind-folded person extended his arm and the angle to which the
> closest person whose body is pointed towards was chosen.
>
> The blind-folded person was Eric and the chosen person was Robert.
> Next to Robert were Sophia and Lydia.

I can't find a good and brief way to say this. How would you reword the first sentence?

Comment: What are you actually writing about.  Are you really trying to describe a children's game? Why?  What is the name of the game (in your language if you don't know in English)? Are you trying to write in a legalistic manner, avoiding all ambiguities because it may be argued in court?

Comment: "The person nearest to the spot he was pointing at..."?

Comment: Just trying to describe it in a casual way.

Comment: How would you say it without using the word spot, and use the word direction or angle?

Comment: The sentence does not really make sense and it is unfair to ask us to guess. When you **extend your arm**, there is generally **no angle**.

Comment: I guess angle generated by the direction of head relative to the direction of the arm.

Comment: Asking how to express an idea, and demanding that certain words are used, makes a bad question!  Are you really trying do describe a children's game? Why? What is the name of the game? Why do you need to use the word angle?   In natural speech we have an idea we want to express and find words to express it.  We don't start with the words and then try to fit them to express an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are making this too hard. You don't need a description that will stand up to analysis by a lawyer. It is probably enough to say

> Eric raised his arm and whoever he pointed at was chosen

At which point you will say "What if he wasn't pointing exactly at a person. I really want to capture the idea of smallest angular separation."

You could say:

> Eric raised his arm and chose whoever was closest to the direction he was pointing.

> Eric raised his arm and whoever he was pointing at (or whoever was closest) was chosen.

Comment: I'm not going to use the words "direction" or "angle", because they aren't necessary and make the description wordy, legalistic and unnatural.